# Why are packages listed as "installed", "installed,automatic", or "installed,local"?

Tags: apt, package-management

I have read [What classifies an application as 'installed' in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113557/what-classifies-an-application-as-installed-in-ubuntu) but it does not address the following issue:

When I run`apt list --installed` on Kubuntu 16.04, I see that all my listed packages have `[installed]` or `[installed,automatic]`. Yet, I've see reports where users have a few or even the majority of their packages being described as `[installed,local]`. And in this, last, case, their packages seem to be outdated.

Is `[installed,local]` the equivalent of what the Synaptic Package Manager would describe as "local or obsolete" as discussed in [What does “local or obsolete” mean in Synaptic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44930/what-does-local-or-obsolete-mean-in-synaptic)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Checking my system using:

```
apt list --installed | awk -F/ '/local]/{print $1}' | xargs apt-cache policy
```

Every package marked `local` has an installed version which is not available in the repositories. For example, I installed `folly` using `checkinstall`. In `apt list --installed`:

```
folly/now 57.0-1 amd64 [installed,local]
```

And for `apt-cache policy`:

```
folly:
  Installed: 57.0-1
  Candidate: 57.0-1
  Version table:
 *** 57.0-1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

You can verify this from the source. `apt list` calls [`apt-private/private-list.cc`'s `DoList()` function](https://alioth.debian.org/scm/browser.php?group_id=31152), which in turn ends up calling [`apt-private/private-output.cc`'s `ListSingleVersion()`](https://github.com/Debian/apt/blob/1d9e29c9e2a5591b42a99a721b901fc003ed9149/apt-private/private-output.cc#L273), where you can see:

```c
 if (state.Upgradable() && state.CandidateVer != NULL)
    strprintf(StatusStr, _("[installed,upgradable to: %s]"),
      CandidateVerStr.c_str());
 else if (V.Downloadable() == false)
    StatusStr = _("[installed,local]");
 else if(V.Automatic() == true && state.Garbage == true)
    StatusStr = _("[installed,auto-removable]");
 else if ((state.Flags & pkgCache::Flag::Auto) == pkgCache::Flag::Auto)
    StatusStr = _("[installed,automatic]");
 else
    StatusStr = _("[installed]");
```