# Is there any command to list "local" packages? like in Synaptic GUI

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, aptitude

I used to look for local packages using Synaptic. Those packages which are locally installed but have no exact match in the current active repositories. As it is explained in this post: [What does “local or obsolete” mean in Synaptic](https://askubuntu.com/q/44930/26246).

I finds that feature very helpful when it comes to debugging [unmet dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/q/140246/26246) issues. While I know how to get [list of obsolete packages](https://askubuntu.com/q/286947/26246), I couldn't find a way for local packages.

So, is there any equivalent command line that lists all local packages?

***Note*** to explain idioms I used.

- *orphan* package: *installed* automatically as dependency, then dependent was removed.
- *obsolete* package: *installed* but no package with same (name,architecture) in the repository.
- *local* package: *installed* but no package with same (name,architecture,*version*) in the repository.

So I don't mean the ***all installed packages***.

***Test Case***

1. Synaptic → Menu:Settings → Repositories → Updates: Enable Unsupported Updates (backports) (Note: I use it as PPA example)
2. Reload package lists
3. Search for `debhelper`, select it. Menu:Packages → Force Version ...: Select and install the version from backports (Usually the highest version)
4. Menu:Settings → Repositories → Updates: Disable Unsupported Updates (backports) (Note: I use it as PPA example)
5. Reload package lists

Compare now between these two lists:

1. Synaptic → SideBar:Status → Installed (local & obsolete)

   [image: Synaptic - local & obsolete packages]
2. `aptitude search '~o'`

   ```
   user@user-vb:~$ aptitude search '~o'
   i A linux-headers-4.15.0-19                          - Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.15.0        
   i A linux-headers-4.15.0-19-generic                  - Linux kernel headers for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP  
   i A linux-image-4.15.0-19-generic                    - Signed kernel image generic                                
   i A linux-modules-4.15.0-19-generic                  - Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86
   i A linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-19-generic            - Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86
   user@user-vb:~$
   ```

Comment: you can list all installed packages using `dpkg -l`

Comment: @Fractalyse, not the complete list of installed packages. There is an idiom misunderstanding, let me update the question.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/965942/158442?

Comment: @muru yes that's exactly, it works for me. The questions are not quite the same also I want to look if there other commands/options. So would you please write an answer.

Comment: maybe something like this: `aptitude search '?narrow(!?origin(.*), ?installed)'`

Comment: @bac0n interesting i didn't think of it. It shows even more packages, I need to verify or extend my test case and put a package with lower version than the ones in repository. Now, I have doubts synaptic list is not the complete list. Could you please put an answer explaining the filter.

Comment: @bac0n same results, i believe `?obsolete` are part of `!?origin(.*)`

Comment: will include it anyway just in case...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find installed packages that does not originate from any source.list or cannot be downloaded.

```
$ aptitude search \
  '?narrow(?or(!?origin(), ?obsolete), ?installed)'
```

Or short form:

```
$ aptitude search '~S (!~O|~o)  ~i'
```

- `?narrow`(filter, pattern)
  Select packages which matches both filter and pattern.
- `?or`(pattern, pattern)
  Matches any of the patterns or both.
- `?origin`(pattern)
  Select packages with given origin.
- `?obsolete`
  Matches installed packages that cannot be downloaded.
- `?installed`
  Select installed packages.
- `?not`(pattern) or `!`
   Select any package not matching the pattern.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works and I am surprised even it list more packages. After I verify with `apt-cache` and https://packages.ubuntu.com, found those packages are the upgradable local packages (local version package that's not in repository and it lower than the highest one in repository). This is more compete list.

Comment: yes, narrow matches filter and pattern on individual package versions.

Answer (score 2):

`apt list --installed` labels packages as `local` in a way that seems to agree with your definition (see [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/965953/158442)). You could filter only packages so labelled with ask, grep, etc.:

```
apt list --installed | awk -F/ '/local]/{print $1}'
```

You could also probably make a similar check using the [Python APT API](https://apt-team.pages.debian.net/python-apt/library/apt_pkg.html#apt_pkg.Version.downloadable).

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly, it has same list as with synaptic . I will give the API a shot later.

Comment: if you need a localized version: https://askubuntu.com/a/1192228/986805

Answer (score 1):

With `apt-show-versions | grep -e 'No available version' -e 'newer than version'` you should get the list of packages:

- without a version in any repo.
- or have higher version than the one in repo.

Probably you need to install it beforehand with `sudo apt install apt-show-versions`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is a partial solution, it covers some cases. `grep 'No available version'` shows only obsolute packages. Using `grep -e 'No available version' -e 'newer than version'`, it adds local packages with version higher than repository. So, it misses only local packages with version lower than repository because they are mixed with other packages require updates.

Comment: So those local packages will have same line as other package from repository that can be upgraded  ( `'upgradable to'`).

Comment: After, I re-verify with Bac0n's answer here https://askubuntu.com/a/1229887/26246 . This answer works and it gives similar results to muru's answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1229857/26246 , same what I asked in the question (synaptic doesn't show local upgradable packages in that list).